# Extensions can not inject html code

Tags: magento-1.7, extensions

I purchased a Google Tag Manager [extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-tag-manager-integration-gtm.html) .
I activated it, and it supposed to inject some html code just after the body tag in my Magento 1.7 version, but it's not .
I installed it locally  (Magento 1.9) and it's working fine .

I also tried other extensions, they work flawlessly locally but not on the 1.7 remote version .

My question is, is there some permissions to set to let the extensions inject html code ? Am I missing something ?

Comment: are you using any theme ? If so you have to move `template` and `layout` files to that theme

Comment: @AnilSuthar : I've done this, but no success . Do not understand why it does not injects HTML code ...

Comment: 1.7 and 1.9 are quite different. If your shop runs on 1.7, you should have a local copy with the same code and not test/develop on 1.9

Comment: Check GTM configuration, (like `Enable/Disable`, etc..) clear/flush cache. Also check if you have ANY advanced cache installed your site.

Comment: Are you sure that your remote code - especially theme - is identical?

Comment: @benmarks : I copied the extension files into the theme directory, and it's not working ... I think that's it's related to php, can it be ? I have php 5.3.3 in my remote server .